# Get cword of visual selection

Tags: vim

In command mode of vim if I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> I get the word under cursor (`<cword>`), this is great for search and replace.

But, If I make a visual selection and press

```
:s/<c-r><c-w>
```

I get the first word in the line of cursor. How I can get the `<cword>` of visual selection?

Comment: If you add one step and yank the selected text (`y`) you can paste it with `<c-r><c-">`.

Comment: if you just want to search without replacement `*` is your friend. either for a selection or for just the word under the cursor.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly using `<c-r><c-w>`, but you may find this useful too:

1. use <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> to yank the current word to register;
2. then, use `:/s/<c-r>0` to paste the word in the register (replaces `<c-r>0`).